# Function to append a string after condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write scalar-valued function in SQL Server and I want to append a string after if condition is met.

If column gdpr_aj = 'a' then I need to append a string 'aj' when column gdpr_sa = 'a' then I need to append a string 'sa' when column gdpr_vs = 'a' then I need to append a string 'vs'.

```
Example data
id   |   gdpr_aj   |   gdpr_sa   |   gdpr_vs   |
1    |     'a'     |      'a'    |     'n'     |
2    |     'n'     |      'n'    |     'a'     |
3    |     'n'     |      'n'    |     'n'     |
4    |     'a'     |      'a'    |     'a'     |
```

Desired result set should be

```
first row @myString = 'aj,sa'
second row @myString = 'vs'
third row @myString = ''
fourth row @myString = 'aj,sa,vs'
```

My function looks like this for now

```
alter function dbo.fn_test (@id as int)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

declare @myString varchar(max)

declare
@gdpr_aj char(1),
@gdpr_sa char(1),
@gdpr_vs char(1)
select
@gdpr_aj = sz.gdpr_aj,
@gdpr_sa = sz.gdpr_sa,
@gdpr_vs = sz.gdpr_vs
from dbo.sz sz where sz.id = @id


if @gdpr_aj = 'a' set @myString = 'aj,'
if @gdpr_sa = 'a' set @myString = 'sa,'
if @gdpr_vs = 'a' set @myString = 'vs'

return @myString

end
```

Comment: try this soultion that mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157797/t-sql-conditional-string-concatenation

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing here?

Comment: @OmidMohammadi thanks for link but it's not scalar-valued function.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty problem is it's not getting concatenated. It evaluates only first if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code will help for desired output

```
alter function dbo.fn_test (@id as int)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

declare @myString varchar(max)

select 
@myString=
case when gdpr_aj ='a' then 'aj,' else '' end +
case when gdpr_sa ='a' then 'sa,' else '' end +
case when gdpr_vs ='a' then 'va,' else '' end 
from dbo.sz where id=@id

return left(@myString,iif(len(@myString)-1>0 ,len(@myString)-1,0))

end

select  dbo.fn_test(1) as myString
select  dbo.fn_test(2) as myString
select  dbo.fn_test(3) as myString
select  dbo.fn_test(4) as myString
```

Sample OutPut

```
myString
---------
aj,sa
va

aj,sa,va
```

Comment: Welcome. The same you can modify with other conditional statement for dynamic output.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code, You are always setting @myString to new value if any field is matched.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_test (@id AS INT)
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(10)
    
        SELECT @output = CONCAT (
                IIF(gdpr_aj = 'a', 'aj,', '')
                ,IIF(gdpr_sa = 'a', 'sa,', '')
                ,IIF(gdpr_vs = 'a', 'vs', '')
                )
        FROM data
        WHERE id = @id
    
        --SELECT @output
        RETURN @output
    END

   SELECT dbo.fn_test(4)
```

Comment: Which sql server version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SQL Server functions, but I know SQL. I suppose the function should look like this:

```
alter function dbo.fn_test (@id as int) returns varchar(max) as
begin
  declare @myString varchar(max)

  select 
    @myString =
      concat_ws(',', 
        case when gdpr_aj = 'a' then 'aj',
        case when gdpr_sa = 'a' then 'sa',
        case when gdpr_vs = 'a' then 'vs')
  from dbo.sz
  where id = @id

  return @myString
end
```